# Why do I have different api responses from Openweathermap JSON and PyOWM library?

Tags: python, openweathermap

I am using two different ways to get current weather and I have got different data from two API.

I suspect PyOWM doesn't work properly because if I changed a city and run a script several times, it hangs with the same data and shows the same cyphers no matter what a city I type in the script. But at least pyowm shows weather pretty close to real if it is launched for first time. Webapi from https://openweathermap.org/ works pretty accurately and I don't have problems with it's JSON response. But PyOWM's response seems to be shows random data. Surely, I could forget about PyOWM and never use it but I am new with this sort of api responses discrepancy and I would like to know whether I do something wrong or I don't understand where I screwed up.

web API https://openweathermap.org/current

```
import json, requests

place = "London"
apikey = "e4784f34c74efe649018567223752b21"
lang = "en"

r = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + place + "&appid=" + apikey + "&lang=" + lang + "&units=metric", timeout=20)
api_answer = json.dumps(r.json())

weather_is = "Now in " + place + ": " + json.loads(api_answer)["weather"][0]["description"] + ".\n" 
t_txt = "Temperature:\n"
t_now = "now: " + str(json.loads(api_answer)["main"]["temp"]) + "\n"
t_max = "maximum: " + str(json.loads(api_answer)["main"]["temp_max"]) + "\n"
t_min = "minimum: " + str(json.loads(api_answer)["main"]["temp_min"])

final_txt = weather_is + t_txt + t_now + t_max + t_min

print(final_txt)
```

PyOWM API https://pyowm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage-examples-v2/weather-api-usage-examples.html

```
import pyowm
owm = pyowm.OWM('e4784f34c74efe649018567223752b21', language = "en")
place = "London"
observation = owm.weather_at_place('place')
w = observation.get_weather()
print("Now in " + place + ": " + w.get_detailed_status() + ".")
temperature_at_place_now = w.get_temperature('celsius')["temp"]
temperature_at_place_max = w.get_temperature('celsius')["temp_max"]
temperature_at_place_min = w.get_temperature('celsius')["temp_min"]

print ("Temperature:")
print ("now: " + str(temperature_at_place_now))
print ("maximum: " + str(temperature_at_place_max))
print ("minimum: " + str(temperature_at_place_min))
```

[web api output]  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAmoO.png)   [pyowm api output]  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkzhb.png)